# Spring mongo and Joda DateTime

Tags: java, spring, jodatime

I have this exception when converting a Long to a Joda DateTime.

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException:
    No converter found capable of converting from type java.lang.Long
    to type org.joda.time.DateTime
```

I'm using

```
        artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>

        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>

        <artifactId>spring-integration-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>

        <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>


        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>

        <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>

        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>

        <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>

        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1.RELEASE</version>
```

Does anyone know what else I need to convert a Long to a DateTime?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Maybe you can also post the piece of code that causes this exception!

Comment: The code is actually inside spring classes. I occurs when deserialising an entity containing a long representation of a DataTime. i.e. GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:177)

Comment: Adding Jodatime tag will attract Jon Skeet's attention ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try the DateTime(long instant) route.  If you need to format, try converting the long to a String and then use the DateTimeFormatter:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

    long abc;  //assign some value to this long
    String s = String.valueOf(abc);  //convert long to string
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");  ///modify this according to your needs    
    DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(date);
```